# PHP array_walk и array_filter

Tags: php, массивы

Выдает вот это: Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference  on line 13
Не могу понять где константа.
postfix не добавляется.

```
$postfix = '_my';

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$files = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($files);

array_walk($files = array_filter($files, function($file_name) {
    return $file_name != '.' && $file_name != '..';
}), function(&$file_name) use($postfix) {
    $file_name .= $postfix;
});

print_r($files);
```

Вот так работает, но сообщение о стандарте так же остается, как будто file_name как не переменная передается.

```
<?php

$postfix = '_my';

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$files = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($files);

array_walk($files = array_filter($files, function($file_name) {
    return $file_name != '.' && $file_name != '..';
}), function(&$file_name, $key) use($postfix, &$files) {
    $files[$key] .= $postfix;
});

print_r($files);
```

Comment: По отдельности естественно тоже работает.

$filtered = array_filter($files, function($file_name) {
    return $file_name != '.' && $file_name != '..';
});


array_walk($filtered, function(&$file_name) use($postfix) {
    $file_name .= $postfix;
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте посмотрим на сигнатуру функции `array_walk()` на [оф.сайте](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk.php) :

```
array_walk ( array &$array , callable $callback [, mixed $userdata = NULL ] ) : bool
```

Первый аргумент передаётся функции по ссылке: array **&**$array 
*(об этом говорит символ амперсанд "&", предваряющий переменную "$array")*. В таких случаях нужно сперва получить значение в переменную:

```
$files = array_filter(...)
```

И только после - передавать переменную в функцию:

```
array_walk($files, function(){})
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не знаете почему так? Ведь на этой строчке я получаю значение(и тут же отдаю)
array_walk($files = array_filter($files, function($file_name) {

Comment: @ValmarLMFAO если вам не понятен этот момент, почитайте про ссылки в php, потому что вы и далее будете натыкаться на такую же ошибку, если попытаетесь в подобной _(принимающей по ссылке)_ функции проделать такой трюк.